# Highlighting text in a textbox using Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, css

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 webapp (with C#). I wanted to add a button which, when clicked would highlight selected text. By 'highlight', I mean change the CSS properties of the text so that it can stand out. I think this can be done with some clientside JavaScript.

I know that you can assign a Javascript function to the onclick event of an HTML input button, but since I'm not very proficient at JS the function itself I have no idea how to write...

Can someone please help?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a jQuery plugin that does something similar to what you want.  Not sure if it works inside of a textbox but it probably wouldn't take much to get it there.  Check out this link:
http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

It seemns to me that  be best solution is to use regex to find searched text and then wrap it in a  tag which has certain desired style assigned to it.

You could look here at w3schools
or briefly

```
var searchString = "abra";
string.replace(searchString,"<span class='highlight'>"+searchString+"</span>")
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

The function:

< script type="text/javascript">

function highlightMyText() {

```
elem=document.getElementById('textToTurnRed');

elem.style.color="red";
```

}

< /script>

Then in the body:

< div id="textToTurnRed">

My text that will be turned red
< /div>

Then the button:

< input type="button" value="Turn Red" onclick="highlightMyText" />

You can do all sorts of stuff with element.style, like change the color, visibility, whatever you need.